# htaccess RewriteRule for unknown folder name not working

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I have been working on this for a few days and had to face the facts...I'm stuck! I have a very simple RewriteRule that works well:

```
RewriteRule ^(.*)testfolder/(.*).php(.*)$ $1newfolder/subfolder/$2.php$3 [L]
```

This changes urls from something like:
    http://mydomain.com/testfolder/phpfile.php#/login
to
    http://mydomain.com/newfolder/subfolder/phpfile.php#/login

The problem is that I need to create a rule that will allow "testfolder" to have a dynamic name. (I have 50+ rules doing this for different folders and I need one rule that catches all of them.)

With no success, I have been trying to use the following to reproduce the results above:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/[a-z]*/(.*).php(.*)$ [NC]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/newfolder/subfolder/$1.php$2$
RewriteRule ^[a-z]*/(.*).php(.*)$ newfolder/subfolder/$1.php$2 [QSA,NC,L]
```

I need to resolve this quickly so any ideas? assistance? or help would be greatly appreciated. Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this rule:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/newfolder/subfolder/ [NC]
RewriteRule ^[^/]+/([^.]+)\.php(.*)$ /newfolder/subfolder/$1.php$2 [NC,L]
```

Comment: I am going to test through this more, but this appears to be working. Thanks a ton. This is going to save me a lot of time.